# javascript console -infinity, what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, console

I´m learning javascript ES6 and I just spotted with -infinity on my console when I run this code:

```js
let numeros = [1, 5, 10, 20, 100, 234];
let max = Math.max.apply(numeros);
console.log(max);
```

What does it mean?

Regards

Comment: If `Math.max` isn't passed any values, it returns the smallest value possible, which is `-Infinity`. See: `console.log(Math.max())`. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-math.max

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first argument of [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is thisArg and you are just passing the [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Parameters) as the array that means it's calling [`Math#max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) without any argument.

As per [MDN docs :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Description)

> If no arguments are given, the result is -Infinity.

In order to fix your problem set `Math` or `null` as [thisArg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Parameters).

```
let max= Math.max.apply(Math, numeros );
```

```js
let numeros= [1,5,10,20,100,234];
    let max= Math.max.apply(Math, numeros );
    
    console.log( max );
```

---

As [@FelixKling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) suggested, ES6 onwards you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to supply arguments.

```
Math.max(...numeros)
```

```js
let numeros = [1, 5, 10, 20, 100, 234];
let max = Math.max(...numeros);

console.log(max);
```

Comment: And since this is ES6, you can do `Math.max(...numeros)`.

Comment: Huh... It also looks like min returns the opposite.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn :  yes it is...[If no arguments are given, the result is Infinity.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

Answer (score 1):

Use an [ES6 Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead:

```js
let numeros = [1, 5, 10, 20, 100, 234];
let max = Math.max(...numeros);
console.log(max);
```

---

As [@Pranav C Balan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3037257/pranav-c-balan) already mentioned, `-Infinity` is what `Math.max()` is supposed to return (defined by spec) if no arguments are given:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Description